# Android, move data between services

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I have this problem, I'm creating an application which runs in background as a service. I've managed to make it persistent and run on boot, which I needed. Right now I have that situation:

In this service I start a thread -> In this thread I would like to start an Intent Service to gather data from GPS (location). This seems easy.

The problem I have is to return the location gathered via Intent Service to this thread.

I found many questions regarding passing data between an activity and a service, but none about services and threads.

I could of course nest my Intent Service inside my main service and change services' variable from Intent Service, checking if it has been changed within a loop. But it seems very inefficient - I would rather do it other way.

Therefore I'd like to ask about how to achieve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: By the way, if You need any specific info please ask, I didn't provide any code because I don't really know which part is relevant and the whole code is going to be quite too long to paste here I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this service I start a thread -> In this thread I would like to start an Intent Service to gather data from GPS (location). This seems easy.

Not really.

> The problem I have is to return the location gathered via Intent Service to this thread.

Then you are doing it wrong.

An `IntentService` is singularly useless for obtaining a location fix. Either the location fix is available immediately (in which case, the `IntentService` was unnecessary), or the location fix will only become available at some arbitrary time in the future (in which case, `IntentService` will have shut down long ago, preventing you from getting the fix reliably in the first place).

If you are using `LocationClient` from the Play Services SDK, just get the location from your thread in your main service.

If you are using `LocationManager` (e.g., you insist that you must use GPS, rather than the "fused location provider" employed by `LocationClient`), you will need to rewrite your app to avoid the blocking-until-the-location-is-available logic. Instead, use event-driven programming, using `requestLocationUpdates()` and processing those locations as they arrive. You can use the variant of `requestLocationUpdates()` that takes a `Looper`, tied to a `HandlerThread` that you create, to be able to process those fixes in a background thread.

Comment: Alright, seems rational. So I have my service, lets call it Service, I use it to launch a thread, call it Thread. Should I put my code gathering the location inside the thread? I need it available from there (at least I think so), since I'm going to send this location to external MySQL which I wanted to do from this thread and then close it. Is there any way to, for instance, create another thread after 5 min, let it finish the work and continue to repeat those steps? Or am I completely wrong and there is no need for the thread?

 I'm using LocationManager.

Comment: What I understand from Your answer I should start a service, from it call all logic to obtain location and use a handlerthread to process (send) the data?

Comment: @Ziker: "I should start a service, from it call all logic to obtain location and use a handlerthread to process (send) the data?" -- correct. Your service would, in `onCreate()` or `onStartCommand()`, set up your `HandlerThread` and your `LocationManager`/`requestLocationUpdates()` config. Then, when a location arrives at your `LocationListener` on your `HandlerThread`, you do something with it. If the "something" is storing locally for later batch upload, you would need something else (e.g., `postDelayed()` on the `Handler`) to arrange to get control periodically for the upload.

Comment: Well, that's great. I mean I started to understand it, I'm quite new to Java at all, so I guess I miss many of useful patterns used in Java and Android. Could You please provide me with a simple example? I understood most of it, but if I set up my HandlerThread (as inner class?) how does it know when the update arrives? Should I pass the thread (an instance or a class?) to requestLocationUpdates as a looper thread? Right? How do I then obtain the location inside the thread? Sorry for that confusing talking, just trying to understand it as well as possible.

Comment: @Ziker: "Could You please provide me with a simple example?" -- not really, as this is not a simple problem. "how does it know when the update arrives?" -- you call `getLooper()` on the `HandlerThread` to get its `Looper`, and you pass that `Looper` with your `LocationListener` to `requestLocationUpdates()`. Your `LocationListener` will be called with `onLocationChanged()` with fixes, and it will be called on the thread supplied by `HandlerThread`.

Comment: Alright, so let's make it a little bit detailed. I think I know how to do so, but please correct me if I'm wrong:

I set a variable in my service of type `Looper` => I then create inner class extending `HandlerThread` => I initialize an instance of this class (`HandlerThread`) which assigns (constructor) the result of `getLooper()` to my `Looper` variable => I also initialize instances of `LocationManager` and `LocationListener` => create a call of `requestLocationUpdates()` where I pass my LocationListener and a `Looper` variable...

Comment: ... => `onLocationChanged()` is called and this is where I should have my db related logic (in `onLocationChanged`), right? :D I hope I wrote it clear, but I have a feeling that I missed something.

Comment: I started implementing it and I got a bit confused. What should I put in this `HandlerThread` besides a constructor to set Looper variable? Also I've noticed I need to set a provider before `requestLocationUpdates`, so after requesting updates I'm unable to switch the provider (e.g. GPS is turned off, I want to use network provider from now on)?

Comment: @Ziker: "What should I put in this HandlerThread besides a constructor to set Looper variable?" -- perhaps nothing. You *get* a `Looper`; you do not set one. "so after requesting updates I'm unable to switch the provider" -- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Comment: Seems well, but doesn't concern my problem. My app (service) is running in background. I need to request updates every 5 min (let's say so, the interval varies). Therefore taking Your approach I have `onCreate` to set up my `LocationManager` and `LocationListener` => then I use `requestLocationUpdates` in `onCreate`. I'm stuck with the provider I set for `requestLocationUpdates` now? Can I possibly overcome this by using `onProviderDisabled/Enabled` to `removeUpdates` and set it up once again inside those functions?

Comment: @Ziker: "Seems well, but doesn't concern my problem" -- it should, particularly http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#BestPerformance. "I'm stuck with the provider I set for requestLocationUpdates now?" -- you are welcome to register for more than one provider. If you have further concerns, please ask a fresh StackOverflow question where you can outline those concerns and somebody can perhaps help you.